# How to get rid of right padding in Eureka ImageRow?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, eureka-forms

I am trying to get rid of the (right) spacing in an image row in Eureka (not on their latest version, but the one before).

Here is the image after uploading:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
form = Section()
   <<< ImageRow("Picture") {
                $0.title = "Select a picture"

                $0.cellSetup({ (cell, row) in
                    cell.height = { 220 }
                    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()
                })
                $0.cellUpdate({ (cell, row) in
                    cell.accessoryView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.width, cell.frame.height)
                    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
                })
   }
```

However, I am just not able to get rid of the space right of the image. What can I do to get rid of it? How can I make the image span the full width of the frame?